# How to get a list of all available themes in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to get a list of all installed themes(e.g "motif" ,"gtk+" etc) in Qt via C++ API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the list of styles that Qt can use then you must use [`QStyleFactory::keys()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html#keys):

```
qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys();
```

Output:

```
("bb10dark", "bb10bright", "cleanlooks", "gtk2", "cde", "motif", "plastique", "Windows", "Fusion")
```

Comment: Are there any analogues for qtquick?